# STL Set inside Map , weird seg fault and Valgrind analysis

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, set, valgrind

I have a weird segmentation fault in my code which use following data structure :

```
map< uint64_t, set<uint64_t> > _key_to_block;
```

Valgrind complain of `_key_to_block.erase(it)` with this message:

```
Address 0x6106118 is 56 bytes inside a block of size 88 free'd
```

for erasing an element from map like this:

```
map< uint64_t, set<uint64_t> >::iterator it     = _key_to_block.find(key);
(it->second).clear();
_key_to_block.erase(it);
```

Moreover, Valgrind also complains of `(it->second).insert(k);` with this massage:

```
Invalid read of size 8
```

for inserting an element in the STL set like this:

```
map< uint64_t, set<uint64_t> >::iterator it = _key_to_block.find(key);
(it->second).insert(value);
```

However, it does not complains of this line :

```
setit = it->second.find(value);
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure your map `_key_to_block` exists? And that you didn't mangle its memory somewhere? Can you post your testcase?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any checks against `end()` so I'm going to take a guess that your `find` calls didn't actually find the key and returned the `end` iterator. Once you start dereferencing that, all bets on behavior are off. You should either use `operator[]` to always create the element or check the results of your `find` against `end`.